# Change list item active bg-color with ng-click

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am a little lost with this issue.

When I click on the - a href tag - i want the li active background color to change to a specific color that I have stored in each object - like so `obj.color" = #5c6bc0`.

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in tags" ng-class="{active: obj.id == tagStates.activeItemID}">
     <a href ng-click="tagStates.activeItemID = obj.id;">
          {{obj.name}}
     </a>
</li>
```

How can I do this? I have tried with ng-style - `ng-style="{'active':'background-color': obj.color}` but that didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in tags" ng-class="{active: obj.id == tagStates.activeItemID}" ng-style={backgroundColor: obj.id == tagStates.activeItemID ? obj.color : ''}">
    <a href ng-click="tagStates.activeItemID = obj.id;">
        {{obj.name}}
     </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function() {
    this.tags = [
      { name: 'bob' },
      { name: 'rick' },
      { name: 'dave' }
    ];
  })

<body ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in vm.tags" ng-class="{'active': vm.active == obj.name}">
      <a ng-click="vm.active = obj.name">{{obj.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{vm.active}}
</body>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/wvKIUtJIb0AE1vpWDtv9?p=preview